# Consuming asmx webservice in windows phone 7 app

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, asmx, service-reference

Created an asmx service. Added service reference in Windows Phone 7 app. Trying to include the using statement with Namespace

using MyWP7APP.Servicereference1;

The statement is not recogonised by intellisense. I just typed it. Any idea why my intellisesnse is not recogonising this service reference. this happens only with one service.

Answer (score 0):

Did you build your solution after you created service reference?

Comment: yes I have rebuilt it. Found a strange thing. In my Servicereference.clientConfig i have only one line of xml. its <configuration />

Comment: :) then I guess you will need to recreate again that proxy

Comment: i deleted and added service reference again and again with no sucess

Comment: Then I guess service is either not working or its WSDL is buggy, can you test service in web browser?

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have the same problem. I think it is a bug in VS.

Try closing then reopening VS then right click on the service reference and select Update Service Reference.